# Perform a sensitivity analysis on neural network in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to find out which variables have the greatest impact on my output variable in a neural network.

The outcome variable is binary and all the predictors (40) are numeric (min-max normalized).

Here I'm building the neural network:

```
set.seed(1)
dt = sort(sample(nrow(jürgens_df), nrow(jürgens_df)*.7))

train<-jürgens_df[dt,]
test<-jürgens_df[-dt,]

# neural net of all numerical values in df (without flagged variables)
nn1 <- nnet(train$is_cancelled~., data = train, size=10)
```

I've been using the [lek.fun][1] package to perform a sensitivity analysis on the network, but the numeric output, found by writing:

```
#Sensitivity analysis on all variables
all_variables <- lek.fun(nn1)
# the numeric value of the sensitivity plot
head(all_variables, val.out=T)
```

... doesn't give me any useful information.

Do you know of any other way of making a sensitivity analysis? Google hasn't been of much help.
Thanks in advance!!
[1]: https://gist.github.com/fawda123/6860630/raw/e50fc6ef30b8269660b4e65aeec7ce02beb9b551/lek_fun.r

Comment: This is the kind of sensitivity analysis I'm referring to: https://imgur.com/a/dxD8Hw2

Comment: You could define the parameters of each sensitivity analysis as a data object within a list, then use map/lapply to perform one analysis per list item (in parallel if you want).

Comment: Could work. I'll give it a try.